# Implementing DES in Python, cannot understand part of the code

Tags: python, encoding

I'm learning how to write the code for DES encryption in Python. I came across this code on Github (link: https://github.com/RobinDavid/pydes/blob/master/pydes.py) but I'm not able to understand a part of the code. (See line 123 in the Github code, also given below:)

```
def binvalue(val, bitsize): #Return the binary value as a string of the given size
    binval = bin(val)[2:] if isinstance(val, int) else bin(ord(val))[2:]   # this is line 124 I'm not getting
    if len(binval) > bitsize:
        raise "binary value larger than the expected size"
    while len(binval) < bitsize:
        binval = "0"+binval #Add as many 0 as needed to get the wanted size
return binval
```

I understand what the function does (as written: #Return the binary value as a string of the given size) but I don't understand how it does it, I don't understand line 124. Thanks for answering.

Comment: what's line 124??

Comment: `binval = "0"+binval`: tell the author that `zfill()` exists.

Comment: Line124 from the link is  binval = bin(val)[2:] if isinstance(val, int) else bin(ord(val))[2:]

Comment: It converts a character or a number to string with zeros and ones, i.e. `3` to `"00011"` for `bitsize` = 5

Comment: I've removed the DES and crypto tags for the simple reason that this is not part of the DES *algorithm*, it's just conversion from number to string. Encoding is an important thing to understand when dealing with crypto, but it's not *part of it*.

Answer (score 2):

```
binval = bin(val)[2:] if isinstance(val, int) else bin(ord(val))[2:]
```

this line is a ternary expression returning the binary value of `val` if `val` is integer, else it does the same but on the ASCII code of `val`.

This is a way (among others) to be compatible with Python 2 and Python 3.

in Python 3, `val` is an integer, as a part of a `bytes` data, when `val` is a 1-sized string as part of a `str` data in Python 2, which doesn't make a difference between binary & string.

In a nutshell, this is a portable way of converting a byte/character to its binary representation as string.

Note that the author could learn more about python since

```
while len(binval) < bitsize:
        binval = "0"+binval
```

could be replaced by `binval = binval.zfill(bitsize)`.